# MacOS is scrambling bluetooth PINs if they contain char values greater than 0x7E

Tags: macos, bluetooth, embedded, ascii, hardware

I'm trying connect a MacOS Monterey 12.3 (M1, 2020) laptop to a bluetooth device typically intended for embedded applications.

The device's bluetooth PIN is the device's address and therefore has char values in the range 0x00 to 0xFF.

If I enter a PIN into the System Preferences > Bluetooth settings GUI such as `0000`, I can see the same pin in Xcode PacketLogger (included in Additional Tools for Xcode):

```
PIN Code Length: 0x04
PIN Code: 0000 (0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30)
```

However if I send a code such as `¡¡¡¡` ( equivalent to `[0xA1, 0xA1, 0xA1, 0xA1]`) then in PacketLogger I see:

```
PIN Code Length: 0x06
PIN Code: Â¡Â¡Â¡ (0xC2 0xA1 0xC2 0xA1 0xC2 0xA1)
```

To enter a pin of `¡¡¡¡` I've tried three approaches:

1. Converting and copy-pasting from an online tool such as [RapidTables](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html)
2. Converting in a python terminal and copy-pasting
3. Setting the Keyboard to "Unicode Hex Input" and directly typing it in by holding down <kbd>option</kbd> and typing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

I'm new to MacOS so not sure if its quirk about how it handles text encodings. Can someone explain to me what I'm seeing?

Comment: `¡` is not equivalent to `0xA1` -- it's the Unicode code point U+00A1, but that expands to `0xC2 0xA1` in UTF-8 (as you're seeing), or `0x00 0xA1` in UTF-16BE, or `0xA1 0x00` in UTF-16LE. I don't know what encoding the Bluetooth standard specifies, but since macOS seems to assume UTF-8, and `0xA1 0xA1 0xA1 0xA` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, I don't think you can do it.

Comment: Is this question about _your_ code? If not it is not an SO question.  If it is, show the code.  You would need to take the UTF-8 and translate it. For two byte UTF-8, the character code is the lower 5 bits of the first character, then the lower 6 bits of the second, giving an 11 bit code.  Codes 0 - 127 are ASCII and normally encoded as a single byte, 128 - 255 are necessarily 2 byte codes because of the way UTF-8 is encoded to indicate that a byte is part of a multi-byte code point.

Comment: This is a bit of an XY problem.  Better perhaps to specify the device, how you have connected it, and what you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: C2A1 has code bits B***00010 **100001,  where * are the encoding bits. So the value B10100001 is 0xA1 (coincidentally in this case - you cannot simply take the second byte and ignore the 0xC2 - it is simply that the ** bits in the second byte are always B10).

Comment: Thanks. I realise now I've held a longstanding conflation between Unicode and UTF. ‍♂️ (U+1F926, [F0 9F A4 A6])
Agreed, what I'm trying to do is not possible with the UTF-8 encoded system preferences gui.